# How to check an app violates Google's the impersonation policy or not

Tags: android, google-play, app-store, google-play-services

My app is removed from Google Play store and got the reason as:

> After review, "My App", has
>   been suspended and removed from Google Play as a policy strike because
>   it violates the impersonation policy.

Is there any other way to check whether the app is obeying all Google's policies (like impersonation) before release. So that the app can be saved from suspension. And more than 3 suspension may cause account termination. So please tell me how can I check the app before release?

I think no one had faced such problem??

For me, I totally agree with the author of [this post](http://iwiz-vicky.blogspot.in/2014/04/play-store-developer-issues-and-how-to.html). Really Nice suggestions.

Comment: Why -ve voting? Please give reasons? Is this a foolish question?? i cant find a good answer even in google search.

Comment: Surely you know yourself if your app is designed to look like some other app or that it were made by some other company.

Comment: Google mainly checks the icon image and name of the app. When I changed may icon image which was similar to another app then the app was accepted which is still in the store. Nothing changed other than the image.

Comment: @Pratheesh after suspend , did u apply for appeal ?

Comment: Yes. But of no use usually. After 4 or 5 a mail will reach you saying these these (same old reasons) are violations you have done so appeal is rejected.

Comment: In my case due to multiple violations my play store account is closed. So created a new account and published the apps which has nothing to do with the violations. Now thinking to republish the app. But really confused about it. As I dont know what is the violation that they are pointing. Now I am publishing the same app other than google play store. Check this [http://appflood.com/blog/ten-alternative-android-app-stores ].

Comment: sad story bro.. most of the forums say if u open a new account , they will find u and ban again ... it is a kind of life time ban... as indie developer , we can't do anything other than just communicate with heartless google bots. ... all the best for your new try :)

Comment: I contacted them .. they reinstate my app :) but i could not save the app's adsense :(

Comment: In which number you contacted? Is you number of downloads saved?? Please tell me in detail about your suspension also. Please reply me ASAP!!! Thanks...

Comment: @Pratheesh how you identified that it was due to app icon?

Comment: @Rakesh Patil I don't remember the message came from playstore on rejection. But I think on google search I got this suggestion from someone. The rejection message I think, didn't contained anything informative. Just an automated one. But now a days I think, it is more clear than before..

Comment: @ParaneetharanSaravanaperumal How you contacted Google. Please tell  me and the comunity. I need it badly. My app is an official app of a FM radio station in my country. But they suspend 2 times after uploading it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not a proper solution for my question. But this is what we can do to sort out this issue from my experience.

I just published another app in the Google Play Store and got rejected. But I didn't published it, it was put for alpha test. This time I got the message that my app is **rejected** because it violates the impersonation policy, not **suspended**. And this time there is an option to correct the APK and resubmit the app. Last time when the app was rejected the app got suspended and I need to change the apps package name. This time the fault was in my side and the part of joy was that in the mail from play store it mentioned that one of the image that I call from JSON to show in the app used image of superman.This was the mail:

> Read through the Unauthorized Use of Copyrighted Content article for more details and examples. Your app contain images of Superman in its activity.

I am very much glad that play store mentioned the real cause of violation this time. Not a simple recorded message.

When we are publishing the app for alpha testing then we get a chance to correct the error and resubmit the apk again. So everyone please try to upload your apk in alpha testing if the app is accepted there then you can transfer it to beta or directly to publish.

Please respond to this answer if anyone have any better or worst experience.

Thanks

Comment: I submitted the app in alpha test but still app got suspened

Comment: Same here. Uploaded a screenshot of one of my other games as a placeholder to get an alpha out for debugging In Apps Purchases and got suspended.

Comment: My app reject because it violates our ads policy. what i do ? please help.

Comment: I published my app to release and got the app suspended the first time. I then published the app to release again and got the app rejected and the cause told to me. So I don't think you got that second message because you went for alpha testing but it's still a really helpful comment.

Answer (score 5):

i had the same problem a few days ago. My app was suspended due to violation of impersonation policy. I got the fixed e-mail and I wondered what things got wrong. I got a try, and sent an official signed letter which mentioned that I had the authority and right to use the company's logo - name and assets for which I made the app. Here you can find the form: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/2993242?visit_id=1-636145321498752102-1429228295&rd=1 My appeal was accepted and my app was reinsteted. From now on, I'll upload first to alpha testing, although I cannot configure yet, if the rejected uploads at alpha testing are calculated against my developer acount cretibility, or because it's alpha testing it has no effect on me. Anyway, the problem remains the same: Many of us don't know the reason what part of our app violated the policy.

Comment: There is no special format. You just write that you have the authority and right to use the company's logo - name and assets for which made the app

Comment: Anastasios, can you provide a pic of the letter u have sent? I have no idea how to make one. I wish I could have a template so I can fill the brackets and send them. That would be huge help. Regards