# Apk suspended violation of impersonation policy while publishing on Google Playstore

Tags: android, google-play, apk, policy

I am publishing an apk on Google Play Store. But my apk is rejected because they say my app is violating [Google Impersonation Policy](https://play.google.com/about/ip-deception-spam/). But they never mentioned what is the reason. I am publishing it to production. Then I found possible violations after I have read the policy.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshots, I am using logos of Whatsapp, Facebook, Viber for social sharing purpose. I am also using Football Team and League Logos. According to the impersonation policy, that can be the only possible reason why my app is suspended. But I think that logos should be allowed to use. In the policy, it states that if I am using logo or copyright thing of others, I can use them if I can show them the permission.

For Facebook logo, Viber logo and Whatsapp Logo, where can I get that permission? Besides, it is not possible to get permission from all football teams to use their logos. Then I found this link - [How to check an app violates Google's the impersonation policy or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126110/how-to-check-an-app-violates-googles-the-impersonation-policy-or-not). In the green answer, it says if I tried publishing as Alpha testing, I will get the reason of suspended. So when I tried with Alpha testing on Google Play Store, it also suspended. But it does not mention the reason of suspended as well. Here is the email I received:

[image]

What is the possible reason my app was suspended? Maybe because of the reason I mentioned? If they are, how can I solve it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the Q & A into an usable answer:

Photo's and logo's have copyrights on them. As a programmer that means you **cannot** use them without (explicit) permission from the owner. Country flags do not fall under that. Google checks for this before release.

Note:

- If you contact the owner of an image and ask for permission use, they might ask for a usage fee.
- If you use images that you get from an API, check the user agreement. If not clear contact the creator of the API.
- Social sharing logo's and button will have details on this, but in general it makes very little sense for them to limit their use.

Why go trough all this trouble?

- Pay people for their work, don't steal.
- You can get sued if you use images without permission.